# Parameterized Raw SQL Update not working in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to parameterize a SQL statement that I am executing with Entity Framework Core 6. The parameters are not working as expected. I expect all of these statements to work but they do not:

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
            $@"UPDATE Schema.Table 
                SET  {columnName}={Convert.ToByte(value)} 
                WHERE Id = {id}");

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
            @"UPDATE Schema.Table 
                SET  {0}={1} 
                WHERE Id= {2}", columnName, Convert.ToByte(value), id);

var p0 = new SqlParameter("@column", columnName);
var p1 = new SqlParameter("@value", Convert.ToByte(value));
var p2 = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
            @"UPDATE Schema.Table 
                SET  @column=@value 
                WHERE Id = @id", p0, p1, p2);
```

I did get it to work with these two queries but they are not properly parameterized:

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
            $@"UPDATE Schema.Table
                SET  {columnName}={{0}} 
                WHERE Id = {{1}}", Convert.ToByte(value), id);

var cmdUpdate = $"UPDATE Schema.Table " +
                $"SET  {columnName}={Convert.ToByte(value)} " +
                $"WHERE Id = {id}";
            await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(cmdUpdate);
```

The problem seems to be with parameterizing the column name but I can not find anything that says I can't do this. Is there a way to parameterize the column name?

Comment: I'd suggest if you are parameterizing column names then you probably have a normalization issue. Columns define what data *is*, they should not themselves be data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can not find anything that says I can't do this

But you won't find anything saying you *can*. That fact, along with your own testing, shows us that it's just not allowed. It has nothing to do with Entity Framework; it's a limitation in SQL Server. Entity Framework uses [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) to execute queries with parameters, and parameters just won't work for column or table names. You're certainly [not the first to ask](https://www.google.com/search?q=t-sql+parameter+column+name).

As you found, you can use C# string interpolation, but be careful. If your `columnName` variable is taken from user input, it will open you up to SQL injection. So make sure it's a real column name before executing your query.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before 
Try this:

```
 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                $"update schema.table 
                set columnName= :value1 
                where columnName= :value2 and columnName is null", value1, value2);
```